# Stanford NLP wrong POS tagging

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have problem with the latest version of stanford pos tagging version 4.0.0 at https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml#Download

I have success in many other sentence but also many simple sentences it's unable to tag then it gives error of "Could not found any models!"

Downloaded model unable to tag sentence such as "when did Michael Jackson die" , but online version is able to tag this.

Also, can I know what training model this one is using  ? Because it's more accurate than the other one, I would love to use this model instead.

http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp

My/PRP$ cat/NN drinks/**VBZ** milk/NN

what/WDT instrument/NN does/VBZ Harold/NNP Faltermeyer/NNP play/**VB**

---

while this one is wrong https://corenlp.run/

My/PRP cat/NN drinks/**NNS** milk/NN

what/WDT instrument/NN does/VBZ Harold/NNP Faltermeyer/NNP play/**NN**

Comment: I just know that "Could not found any models!" is nothing to do with the stanford tagger, it's the php library error message. so the only problem here is wrong pos tagged.

Answer (score 1):

The constituency parser will produce part-of-speech tags as well, so you can get those tags by running the constituency parser without using the part-of-speech tagger.

The part-of-speech tagger probably lacks enough questions in the training data, so in future versions we can try to augment the training data some more. Thanks for bringing up these error examples.

Comment: Hi, can you let me know what model is this using ? Where can 
 i download this model ? Because it will solve my problem, thank you 
 http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp

Comment: It appears to be using the englishPCFG parser from several years back. You can find older models here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/history.html

Comment: The parser demo page claims it was last updated in September 2016.

Comment: hi, thanks. Can I ask one more question, is it possible to get the POS tagged corpus used by Stanford POS tagger, so that I can add additional sentences that doesn't work in the current model and then retrain the model myself. Can i download those corpus somewhere ?

Comment: Many of the data sets are publicly available but we cannot distribute our copy of them. You need to look for OntoNotes 5.0, English Web Treebank, and Penn Treebank online as the main ones, though we also have some in house data sets we don't distribute at this time, and we also use the Craft biomedical corpus.

Comment: So if you google "OntoNotes 5.0", "English Web Treebank", "Penn Treebank", "Craft biomedical" you will get links to the various data sets we use.

Comment: Also look for "Stanford QuestionBank"

Comment: There is also a small private data set we use, that is the one thing not publicly available at this time.